# Xubuntu indicator plugin background

Tags: xubuntu, themes, indicator, design, numix

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 and my indicator plugin has white background in most themes. It looks like [this](http://piccy.info/view3/8625816/0897e79fc3ffd7e44234bdc7fb6c1bdb/) (Numix).

But in **Adwaita** and **High Constrast** themes it works properly. Screenshot [here](http://piccy.info/view3/8625866/5766e5e0a10e80579859d90dd99c089a/).

Question is what fix do I need to perform in order to make Indicator plugin background in Numix transparent like it's done in Adwaita and High Contrast themes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I removed Indicator plugin from the panel and after `xfce4-panel -r` most indicators went to Notification area. Unfortunately, sound indicator disappeared, but I solved the problem by installing `xfce4-mixer` which does the same job, but looks slightly different.

Now the panel looks smooth.

Comment: yes, but some apps can work only with Indicator plugin, like hipchat.

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal and type:`sudo vi /usr/share/themes/name/gtk-3.0/apps/xfce.css`. You will find something like this:

```
.xfce4-panel .button {
    border-image: none;
    background-color: #454545;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 1px;
    color: @dark_fg_color;
    text-shadow: none;
```

Change '*background-color: #454545;*' to '*background-color: transparent;*'
then logout and login and that's it

*Ps, name is the theme name.*

Comment: What if the theme I'm using isn't listed in /usr/share/themes? (I installed it by drag-and-dropping into the Appearance menu Style tab)

Comment: @weronika I am not sure where drag-and-dropping saves the theme, but I suspect it's `~/.local/share/themes`.