# Xubuntu 16.04 - Volume indicator missing

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, indicator, volume-control

Recently, I've got my Xubuntu to 16.04 and I found indicators in `xfce4-panel` have a problem.

As shown in the picture below, volume indicator is missing.

[image]

As ugly background color, I don't want to use `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin` and `xfce4-mixer` is unavailable.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still have `xfce4-mixer` in Xenial Xerus, though it was removed from official repository for some reasons.

Go to this link of [ubuntuupdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_import/rafaela/import/base/xfce4-mixer) and download the mixer package's deb file. And then install it with `dpkg -i` command or gdebi. This worked for me in 16.04 and it doesn't have white background.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Who downvoted this and why?

Comment: @SMizuho Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You might have indicator-plugin missing from the panel.

Right click on the panel and select

> Panel -> Panel Preferences -> Items and click on the + button

Search for Indicator Plugin and add it.

I hope that works.

Comment: Oh yes, indicator-plugin missing as you suggest.

But with indicator-plugin, [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663248/xubuntu-indicator-plugin-background)  problem worries me.....

Answer (score 1):

All settings->Sound -> bottom checkbox "Show sound volume in the menu bar"